# How can I generate JSON Overlays for GWT with Enunciate?

Tags: json, gwt, jersey, enunciate

The [Enunciate homepage](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/) gives only clues how to create client-side libraries for a [GWT-RPC-API](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/module_gwt.html#artifacts), but I have developed a REST API, so it would be cool if JSON overlays could also be generated with Enunciate. (I use it for creating other libraries too.) Enunciate says the feature already exists but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a useful sample called [pet clinic](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/blob/master/integration-tests/petclinic/enunciate.xml), which shows the basic procedure.